# Draw Route from my location to destination location using google API

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I tried to make a google map where using location ,i get my location's lon,lat.
Here is my code

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + (myLocation.getLatitude())+","+(myLocation.getLongitude())+"&daddr="+destLat+","+destLon;

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

It runs but nothing is happen. just show my location.Can any one tell me where is the error in declaration??Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete source code at https://github.com/frogermcs/RoutePathExample for how to draw path between two geolocation. I use this code without any trouble at all. You should check it

Comment: I can draw route between two points.But i want to draw route from my location to destination.Here is the question is how can i get my lon,lat from my  location using Google API.I already post my code.Have a look,Is there any error in declaration?

Comment: Google does not respond to KML anymore :(.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
private boolean gps_enabled = false;
private boolean network_enabled = false;
private LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {

    }

    if (gps_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 10, locListener);
    }
    if (network_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 10, locListener);
    }

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            currentLocation = location;


    }



    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And then once you get location you  can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=<start lat>,<start lon>&daddr=<dest lat>,<dest lon>"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Here <start lat>,<start lon> need to be my lat ,lon...which i do not know,but i have to find it by using location

Comment: `gps_enabled,network_enabled` how can and what type i need to declar them?

Comment: ,in here `gps_enabled,network_enabled` how can and what type i need to declared them?are they `private boolean gps_enabled;
 private boolean network_enabled;`???????